# Something interesting about how python do GC

Tags: python, garbage-collection, release

I wrote the following code to check how python releases it's object memory , well, I found something interesting, but I am not sure, So I am posting it here to ask for help.

First

```
class A():
    def __del__(self):
        print "A __del__"

class B():
    def __del__(self):
        print "B __del__"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    b = B()
    print "main leaving"
```

the output is :

```
main leaving
A __del__
B __del__
```

It seems when the object leaves its' area, it will call the **del** function to release its resource, first main leave, then A **del**, last B.

```
I thought may be A & B's __del__ function call's sequence is influenced by the object declare sequence, so I write it like this:

class A():
    def __del__(self):
        print "A __del__"

class B():
    def __del__(self):
        print "B __del__"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B() ### declare b first
    a = A()
    print "main leaving"
```

well, the output is same.

Then I rewrite the code as this

```
   class B():
        def __del__(self):
            print "B __del__"

    class A():
        def __del__(self):
            print "A __del__"


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        a = A()
        b = B()
        print "main leaving"
```

however ,the result is the same.

So, it seems that the python interpreter has got a dict of all objects it has , and when the object leaves its area, it will release its resource by the dict sequence, which may be the same as the alph sequence, is this true?

Comment: AFAIK CPython will delete the object when, during `Py_DECREF`, the reference count goes to 0. The order in which references are decremented when leaving a certain block is an implementation detail. It completely depends on how the code is compiled to bytecode(and, in case of deleting a `dict`, it probably depends on the order of the keys which *could* be random[i.e. change at every execution, especially in new versions of python with hash randomization active]).

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the GC deletes vars in alphabetical order.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __del__(self):
        print self.val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = A(2)
    a = A(1)
    c = A(3)
    d = A(4)
    print 'Bye!'

Bye!
1
3
2
4
```

But it doesn't always work.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __del__(self):
        print self.val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = A(2)
    a = A(1)
    d = A(4)
    c = A(3)
    print 'Bye!'

Bye!
1
3
2
4
```